# Why do Infected people in Resident Evil 6 turn into insect-like life forms? (Spoilers)

Tags: resident-evil-6

I am currently going through Chris's gameplay and realised that the J'avo turn into insect like creatures such as spiders, centipedes, and wasps etc ... Also, the last Boss in Leon's mission is a giant mantis like creature ...

Can anyone give me a source for me to read that has more on this ?? Why insects ? Is the C-virus engineered on bug's DNA or something ?

Comment: Lol at the down-votes ...

Comment: Extra downvotes for extra lols.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest checking out the [C-Virus page](http://residentevil.wikia.com/C-Virus) on the [RE Wikia](http://residentevil.wikia.com/), as the virus articles are pretty detailed. Here's an excerpt that more directly references what you're asking about, though:

> Overall, the C-Virus combines the traits and abilities of the two viruses it was derived from, possessing the adaptive mutations of the G-virus and the combustible properties of the T-Veronica virus. The T-Veronica virus is visible in some of the mutations where the mutations usually result in the development of insect-like appendages.

---

> The t-Virus can only properly function by consuming the cell in order to produce its energy. This slow breakdown of cells leads to the gradual breakdown of the host, causing necrosis. The virus incorporates itself into the host's DNA, which substantially alters it. This is why creatures, such as bees and spiders, only have very minor mutation, such as increased size, when compared to the human mutation caused by the virus.
>
> Within the time frame of an hour, the decayed skeletal and muscular system is reconstructed into a stronger and more durable form. Development can be seen of sharp canine teeth and razor claws, fresh blood seeps into remaining skin giving it a reddish hue, advances in decomposition, and intact eyes become a bright white. Umbrella researchers at the Arklay Laboratory have dubbed this stage "V-ACT", referring to the resulting creature also known as a "Crimson Head". To awaken, the brain must be jolted back to consciousness with a slight but important increase in intelligence, and large increase in agility and aggressiveness.

The form the T-Virus takes on depends on the physical state of the host, whether they be living, near dying or dead, and whether they're a human or an animal/insect. The C-Virus uses the T-Veronica virus as a base, so the insect and animal related atributes present in the T-Virus are also found in the C-Virus.

Comment: But does it state why ? Or is there no background evidence of why mutations result in the development of insect-like appendages ?

Comment: I gave that wiki a read, they mention a lot about insect like formations but no explanation `why` that happens. Why not replicate stronger monsters that have mammal physique ? why `insects` in particular ??

Comment: @Render - I realize I'm a little late here, but since this got bumped...  One of the components of the T-Veronica was a retrovirus that came from fossilized ants, hence the insectoid appearances.

Comment: @Shinrai Finally !!! Someone with an answer .. can you provide a source ? If so, add this as a separate answer.

Comment: @Render - I'm sure it's mentioned in Code: Veronica at some point, but I haven't played it in like a decade so I really can't be more specific off the top of my head.  I do very strongly remember that it had something to do with ants, though.  (And hey, just look at the endgame of CV...)

Answer (score 0):

Since someone else already linked you to the wiki, I'm not going to do it again. However, as to your actual question, there's nothing but speculation out there. My own particular take on it, which I advise you to take with a grain of salt, is that insectoid-like mutations tend to have exoskeletons built around them that, enhanced with the powers of the C-Virus, give them an effective layer of protection against weaker attacks (look at how the Napads can get ridiculously hard to kill if you can't break the solid crap they have on their backs to attack their weak spot).

Like I said, at this point it's all speculation, since as far as I know, nothing has been . You're free to form your own opinion on the matter, or to take someone else's that you consider to be convincing.